# Assign RunID on changing category

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to assign a RunID to a person performing different tasks. A new RunID should be assigned whenever the task changes, and of course this should change per person, too.

This is some example data with the expected RunID already added.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-01', 1],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-02', 1],
            ['A', 'T2', '2023-01-03', 2],
            ['A', 'T2', '2023-01-04', 2],
            ['A', 'T2', '2023-01-05', 2],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-06', 3],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-07', 3],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-08', 3],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-09', 3],
            ['A', 'T1', '2023-01-10', 3],
            ['B', 'T1', '2023-01-01', 4],
            ['B', 'T1', '2023-01-02', 4],
            ['B', 'T1', '2023-01-03', 4],
            ['B', 'T1', '2023-01-04', 4],
            ['B', 'T1', '2023-01-05', 4],
            ]),
            ['Person', 'Task', 'Time', 'expectedRunID'])
```

I thought I could do it by defining a window and assigning a dense_rank

```
window = Window.partitionBy("Person").orderBy("Task")
df.withColumn("runID", F.dense_rank().over(window))
```

This somehow works, but it does not assign the reoccuring T1 for personA to runID 3, but since it is the same person-task combination it is also assigned runID 1.

Any ideas, how to handle this?

Comment: Shoudn't runID for person B should be 1 and not 4, since you want to do it for each person partition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
w=Window.orderBy(F.asc("Person"),F.asc("Time"))

df\
    .withColumn("change", F.when((F.lag("Task").over(w)==F.col("Task")) & (F.lag("Person").over(w)==F.col("Person")), 0).otherwise(1))\
    .withColumn("run_id", F.sum("change").over(w))\
    .show()
```

Input:

```
+------+----+----------+-------------+
|Person|Task|      Time|expectedRunID|
+------+----+----------+-------------+
|     A|  T1|2023-01-01|            1|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-02|            1|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-03|            2|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-04|            2|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-05|            2|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-06|            3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-07|            3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-08|            3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-09|            3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-10|            3|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-01|            4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-02|            4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-03|            4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-04|            4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-05|            4|
|     B|  T2|2023-01-06|            4|
+------+----+----------+-------------+
```

Output (I kept the intermediate column for understanding, you can drop it):

```
+------+----+----------+-------------+------+------+
|Person|Task|      Time|expectedRunID|change|run_id|
+------+----+----------+-------------+------+------+
|     A|  T1|2023-01-01|            1|     1|     1|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-02|            1|     0|     1|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-03|            2|     1|     2|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-04|            2|     0|     2|
|     A|  T2|2023-01-05|            2|     0|     2|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-06|            3|     1|     3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-07|            3|     0|     3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-08|            3|     0|     3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-09|            3|     0|     3|
|     A|  T1|2023-01-10|            3|     0|     3|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-01|            4|     1|     4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-02|            4|     0|     4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-03|            4|     0|     4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-04|            4|     0|     4|
|     B|  T1|2023-01-05|            4|     0|     4|
|     B|  T2|2023-01-06|            4|     1|     5|
+------+----+----------+-------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a combination of window functions:

```
w = Window.orderBy("Person", "Time")
df = df.withColumn("Prev_Task", lag("Task", 1, None).over(w)) \
    .withColumn("Prev_Person", lag("Person", 1, None).over(w)) \
    .withColumn("runID",
                when((col("Prev_Task").isNotNull and col("Task") != col("Prev_Task")) | (
                            col("Person") != col("Prev_Person")), 1).otherwise(0)) \
    .withColumn("runID", sum("runID").over(w) + 1).drop("Prev_Task", "Prev_Person")
df.show(100, False)
```

Result:

```
+------+----+----------+-----+
|Person|Task|Time      |runID|
+------+----+----------+-----+
|A     |T1  |2023-01-01|1    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-02|1    |
|A     |T2  |2023-01-03|2    |
|A     |T2  |2023-01-04|2    |
|A     |T2  |2023-01-05|2    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-06|3    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-07|3    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-08|3    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-09|3    |
|A     |T1  |2023-01-10|3    |
|B     |T1  |2023-01-01|4    |
|B     |T1  |2023-01-02|4    |
|B     |T1  |2023-01-03|4    |
|B     |T1  |2023-01-04|4    |
|B     |T1  |2023-01-05|4    |
+------+----+----------+-----+
```